# Generate a password dictionary from simple information

Tags: password-cracking, dictionary

Suppose that we are going to perform a dictionary attack to crack the password of a known account. If we have some simple information from the account owner, such as first name, surname, age, date of birth, birthplace, etc, in form of a wordlist, is there any tool to automatically generate a more complex password dictionary, say by combining different words, capitalizing them, mutating, etc?

Comment: in fact, it's part of a university course project.

Comment: Of course, the course did not tell us to do so. We want to propose building an automated tool for cracking passwords based on simple information as our course project. So I just want to know whether there is any tool already present or not.

Comment: I see. Well, your question by itself seems reasonable. However, I think our site policies will prevent you from getting a specific product recommendation. Maybe someone else (besides me) knows something that can help you.

Comment: I think the exercise of cracking password hashes ranks pretty low on the 'real-world usefulness' scale. Such is the typical case of university IT courses. I suppose such an exercise has some benefits, but it just seems to me that exercises in defense would be more 
useful and morally rewarding.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey I'm inclined to disagree. Cracking passwords is still insanely useful in real-world engagements; resulting from the continued use of weak passwords. User education has its place and may help reduce the effectiveness of password guessing/cracking, but I still routinely crack 60-80% of an entire Domain's hashes on a typical pentest.

Comment: @GeorgeBailey Thanks for your advice. Actually, I have a few projects in my mind and I'm now checking the feasibility of each one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an open source tool out there that does this. It's called [CeWL](https://digi.ninja/projects/cewl.php). It comes with Kali Linux or available on [GitHub](https://github.com/digininja/CeWL/).

You can also use [Crunch](http://tools.kali.org/password-attacks/crunch).

A third option: [Transmute.py](https://github.com/eshork/transmute)